# Wordpress Ajax Custom Query - High CPU LOAD

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I'm developing a fully AJAX community WP theme that comes with a lot of custom queries.

Everything is fine, there is no bug but recently but I had a few clients that have a huge database and my theme started to kill the CPU. I wonder how can I make it run faster.

#### What this code is doing?

This code is  trying to get posts that contains only have "comment" type comments (comment_type="comment") AND approved ones.

**database information:** Mysql - mariaDB

**table name I'm trying to get result** - wp_comments

**how many data that table have -** 380.000 (380K) comments

**query's raw output time on phpmyadmin (w/o php) -** 0.23 seconds

**time to get this data on front end -** 0.85-90 seconds

**JS Code that calls function**

```
    function lfload(page) {
  $("#sol-load").css("opacity","0.75");
  document.cookie = "lf= popular;  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
  document.cookie = "popular_page = " + page + ";  expires = Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", bilgi.tema_url + '/admin-ajax.php', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("sol-load").innerHTML = this.response;
      $("#sol-load").css("opacity","1");
  }
  }
  xhr.send("action=popular_ajax");
}
```

**PHP Code to get data**

```
function popular_ajax()
  {
          global $wpdb;
           // getting latest page from cookie
          if (isset($_COOKIE["popular_page"]) AND 
          $_COOKIE["popular_page"] != 0) {
              $latest_sent_page_no = intval($_COOKIE["popular_page"]);
          } elseif (!isset($_COOKIE["popular_page"]) OR
           $_COOKIE["popular_page"] == 0) {
              $latest_sent_page_no = 1;
          }
          $page = $latest_sent_page_no;
          $cur_page = $page;
          $page -= 1;
          $per_page = 20;
          $start = $page * $per_page;
          $count_limiti = $per_page*50; 
          // tried to limit count 
          //query to make it more faster but did'nt work
          // count how many page exists to use it for pagination
          $count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT comment_post_ID)
           FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."comments
           USE INDEX (left_frame_index) 
           WHERE comment_approved = 1 
           AND comment_type = 'comment' 
           LIMIT $count_limiti");
          $sorgu = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID 
            FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."comments 
          USE INDEX (left_frame_index) 
          WHERE comment_approved = 1
           AND comment_type = 'comment' 
           GROUP BY comment_post_ID 
           ORDER BY MAX(comment_date) 
           DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
          // GET DATA FROM SQL
          foreach($sorgu as $goflying2){
              // Çıktı bölgesi
              $msg .= "<li class='has-border-bottom'><a class='pr-0 pl-0 pt-1 
              pb-2 is-size-8'
               href='". get_permalink($goflying2->comment_post_ID) ."'
                title='".get_the_title($goflying2->comment_post_ID)."'>
                ".get_the_title($goflying2->comment_post_ID)."<span class='badge'>
                " .clean_comment_count_wo_newbies($goflying2->comment_post_ID). 
                "</span></a></li>";
          }
          wp_reset_postdata();
          // SAY THERE IS NO DATA IF ITS EMPTY
          if ($count == 0) {
            echo '<div class="tag has-text-centered has-fullwidth">
            <a class="pr-0 pl-0 pt-2 pb-2 is-size-8 has-text-dark">
            '.__("gündemimiz boş...", 'hype-community').'</a></div>';
              exit;
          }
          // PAGINATOIN STARTING HERE
          $no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);
          $start_loop = 1;
          $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
          //conditional pagination
          if ($cur_page > 1) {
              $pre = $cur_page - 1;
              $pag_container .= "
              <button onclick='gundemNav(this)' value='$pre' class='button is-small'>
                <i class='fa fa-angle-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>
              </button>
              ";
          }
  
          $pag_container .= "
          <div class='dropdown is-hoverable has-fullwidth'>
        <button class='button is-small ml-3 mr-3 dropdown-trigger 
        has-fullwidth' aria-haspopup='true' aria-controls='dropdown-menu5'>
           <span>$cur_page</span>
           <span class='icon'>
    <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>
         </span>
            </button>
              ".'<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu5" role="menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">';
      // tried to limit for loop
          if ($end_loop > 50) {
              $end_loop = 50;
          }
          for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {
            // loop to print all page numbers
              if ($cur_page == $i) {
                  $pag_container .= "<a value='$i' class='dropdown-item 
                  is-active'>$i</a>";
              } else {
                  $pag_container .= "<a onclick='gundemNav(this)' value='$i'
                   class='dropdown-item'>$i</a>";
              }
          }
          $pag_container = $pag_container . "
  </div></div>
          </div>";
          if ($cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
            //conditional pagination output
              $nex = $cur_page + 1;
              $pag_container .= "
              <button onclick='gundemNav(this)' value='$nex' class='button is-small'>
                <i class='fa fa-angle-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>
              </button>
              ";
          }
          if ($no_of_paginations == 1) {
            //conditional pagination output
              print     '<aside class="menu"><ul class="menu-list">' . $msg . 
              '</ul></aside>';
          } elseif ($cur_page == 1 and $no_of_paginations >= 2) {
            //conditional pagination output
              print     '<aside class="menu"><ul class="menu-list">' . $msg . 
              '</ul></aside>';
              echo  '
              <button onclick="gundemNav(this)" value="'. $nex .'" 
              class="button is-small is-bg-blue has-text-white is-fullwidth mt-3">
                <span class="icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
                <strong>'.__("fazlasını yükle", 'hype-community').'</strong>
              </button>
              ';
          } elseif ($cur_page != 1 and $no_of_paginations > 1) {
              //conditional pagination output
              echo
           '<div class="has-text-centered is-flex mb-3">'.$pag_container .
            '</div>'. // pagination
          '<aside class="menu"><ul class="menu-list">' . $msg . 
          '</ul></aside>'; // content that called from wpdb get results
          }
          // kill ajax
          exit;
  }
```

**INDEX I used in this query**

```
left_frame_index -> commenst_post_ID, comment_date, comment_approved, comment_type
```

How can I make it run faster, be more stable? Is there something wrong with my SQL code or PHP code? This code is really killing the CPU...

Without this index, query is around 0.5 seconds (phpymyadmin exec. time. 1.5 seconds when calling with AJAX).

sorry for my bad English! ^_^

Comment: Please, format long lines to fit in one screen.

Comment: hello! yes, sorry. I formatted my code.

Comment: Why do you tell the queries to use a specific index? Databases are usualy smart enough to decide on their own what index to use if any to get the best performance for any given query.

Comment: tbh I wanted to be sure but I was trying to fix this query last 10 hours. Now my query working  exec time 0.056 seconds. But IDK when I'm trying spamming this ajax button with my mouse; my cpu goes crayz. I set a transient to count query (deleting it with new comments) but cpu still get hurts when I'm spamming it.

But I switched to twentynineteen theme and spammed my f5 @home page and cpu went to %60 70 again. This makes me think everything is OK with my code but there is a problem with my hosting.

Comment: You're using both `DISTINCT comment_post_ID` and `GROUP BY comment_post_ID` in your query. Either one will be enough. I doubt this will affect CPU usage, but it is worth testing which variant is performs best. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql

Comment: I see 4 probles 1. For pagination -> `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, 2. Free result after sql (free memory) query `$result->free();`  3. `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` - use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.  4 Security html output (XSS - problem).

Comment: And  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT` gives you a one number, you don't need to use pagination:)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT comment_post_ID)
>     FROM  ".$wpdb->prefix."comments USE INDEX (left_frame_index)
>     WHERE  comment_approved = 1
>       AND  comment_type = 'comment'
>     LIMIT  $count_limit
> ```

Needs a better index; see the below.

Do NOT compare a VARCHAR (such as `comment_approved`) with a numeric literal (such as `1`), the index cannot be used.  Put quotes around `"1"` or `'1'`.

Get rid of the "index hint"; it may be hurting more than helping.

Why no `ORDER BY`?  A limit without an order-by give you "random" rows.

Oops, the real problem is that the query generates only 1 row, so there is no use in having a `LIMIT`.  Keep the `DISTINCT`; toss the `LIMIT`.

> ```
> SELECT  DISTINCT comment_post_ID
>     FROM  ".$wpdb->prefix."comments USE INDEX (left_frame_index)
>     WHERE  comment_approved = 1
>       AND  comment_type = 'comment'
>     GROUP BY  comment_post_ID
>     ORDER BY  MAX(comment_date) DESC
>     LIMIT  $start, $per_page
> ```

See above, plus

Don't mix `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`.  Use only the `GROUP BY`.

This query needs a different index (use the specified order):

```
INDEX(comment_type, comment_approved, comment_post_ID, comment_date)
```

I suspect this query is not giving you what you expect?  Please describe in English what the goal is.

Pagination via `OFFSET` has problems.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Answer (score 1):

## Overall comments

Overall I’d say that the practice of sending HTML in an AJAX response and using that to directly set the content of a DOM element is an antiquated practice, and [could be an XSS avenue](https://labs.f-secure.com/blog/getting-real-with-xss/). While the practice of [sending data from the API and having the front end code construct the HTML dynamically may have been a new construct eight years ago](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140036/is-it-a-good-idea-to-do-ui-100-in-javascript-and-provide-data-through-an-api) it is much more common in today’s web.

## Improving speed of code to lookup posts

To answer your question "*How can I make it more faster, more stable.*" it looks like there is a query to get IDs for each post, and then in the loop to create list items, there are calls to `get_permalink()`, `get_the_title()` and `clean_comment_count_wo_newbies()`. Do those function calls run queries against the database? If so, that would likely be the bottleneck. Ideally the code would run a single query to get all the information needed - e.g. IDs, titles, comment counts, etc. Remember that DB queries **are expensive** so it is best to minimize the number of queries needed.

## JavaScript

### DOM Access

The code looks up the element with id *sol-load* three times within a few lines. It would be wise to cache those lookups, since they can be expensive.

[image: bridge toll]

> *”...DOM access is actually pretty costly - I think of it like if I have a bridge - like two pieces of land with a toll bridge,  and the JavaScript engine is on one side, and the DOM is on the other, and every time I want to access the DOM from the JavaScript engine, I have to pay that toll”*
>     - John Hrvatin, Microsoft, MIX09, in [this talk *Building High Performance Web Applications and Sites*](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09/T53F) at 29:38, also cited in the [O'Reilly *Javascript* book by Nicholas C Zakas Pg 36](https://books.google.com/books?id=ED6ph4WEIoQC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=John+Hrvatin+%22DOM%22&source=bl&ots=2Wrd5G2ceJ&sig=pjK9cf9LGjlqw1Z6Hm6w8YrWOio&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcmZ7U_eDeAhVMGDQIHSfUAdoQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=John%20Hrvatin%20%22DOM%22&f=false), as well as mentioned in [this post](https://www.learnsteps.com/javascript-increase-performance-by-handling-dom-with-care/)

```
const solLoad = $("#sol-load");
```

### AJAX

The front end code uses jQuery to access DOM elements yet the AJAX code uses vanilla XHR mechanisms. The jQuery AJAX methods like [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) could be used to simplify the code. Actually [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) can be used to simplify the code dramatically -

I haven't tested this but this should be what would be needed:

```
solLoad.load(bilgi.tema_url + '/admin-ajax.php', {action: 'popular_ajax'}, 
    solLoad.css.bind(solLoad, "opacity", 1));
```

### Inline event handlers

There are event handlers registered within the HTML code - e.g.

> ```
> <button onclick='gundemNav(this)'
> ```

It is better to register event handlers within the JavaScript (e.g. using [`button.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (can be done when element is created or after is is selected via DOM) for multiple reasons:

1. The logic can be separated from the markup - if multiple teammates worked on the project then one could work on the JavaScript while the other could work on the HTML independently.
2. Such handlers can pollute the global namespace which can lead [to strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045/1575353).